Why the Plugin with id 'com.android.application' is not found in Android Studio?
I got the below error while building my code in Android Studio. It looks like the app is not able to locate the root folder where the build file is located.
Please help me resolve this issue.
**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

* Where:
Build file '/Users/wshchannel4/AndroidStudioProjects/streamit_flutter_v8.6.0_update_code/android/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 730ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

